Why is the page still loading after an redirect?
I have an strange problem which I can't find out what is causing this behaviour.
I have an page called dashboard.php where I have this code:
mail('xxx@gmail.com', 'Dashboard 1', 'isLoggedin = ' . $isLoggedIn);

if(!$isLoggedIn) {
  header("Location: https://example.com/account/login.php");
}

mail('xxx@gmail.com', 'Dashboard 2', 'Dashboard 2');

If the user isn't logged on the dasboard.php page, he must be redirected to the login.php page.
When I am not logged in and go to dashboard.php, the following happened:

I got the first mail where isLoggedin is empty (which is correct ofcourse)
I got redirected to the login.php page which is also correct
I got the second 'Dashboard 2' mail which I don't understand.

Why get I the second mail but I am redirected to the login.php so the script in dashboard.php shouldn't get so far? Why is the script after the redirect still running?

After your header() line, you didn't stop the code using exit();, or make good use of else case.

Ths question rather why shouldn't it?

as shown in php.net docs, you have to exit; your script, otherwise it will be executed.

Try to use exit(); or die(); to finish rendering page and go next to header. It might be solution.
Die in PHP
Exit in PHP
